# How to solve the ERROR Cannot locate rosdep definition for [PCL]?

Tags: ros2, pcl

Im trying to use the github package for 2D LiDAR-based odometry in ROS2 humble. This is the package github

[Simple-2D-LiDAR-Odometry](https://github.com/dawan0111/Simple-2D-LiDAR-Odometry)

I installed the dependencies required with

> sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev libpcl-dev

Then when try to run `rosdep install -i --from-path src --rosdistro humble -y` I got the following error:

> ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys
> resolved to system dependencies: lidar_odometry: Cannot locate rosdep
> definition for [PCL]

I tried to search everything but still no help. The package .xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>lidar_odometry</name>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <description>2D LiDAR Odometry package. using GICP</description>
  <maintainer email="msd030428@gmail.com">KDW</maintainer>
  <license>Apache 2.0</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>
  
  <depend>rclcpp</depend>
  <depend>nav_msgs</depend>
  <depend>sensor_msgs</depend>
  <depend>geometry_msgs</depend>
  <depend>Eigen3</depend>
  <depend>PCL</depend>
  <depend>laser_geometry</depend>
  <depend>pcl_conversions</depend>
  <depend>tf2</depend>
  <depend>tf2_eigen</depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

Any help?

Comment: I think `<depend>PCL</depend>` is wrong. Maybe try `<depend>libpcl-all-dev</depend>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned that `pcl` is not a official ros package, so you can't install it with rosdep. Instead, you should install it with `apt-get` using `sudo apt-get install libpcl-dev`. After that, add `--skip-keys pcl` to your rosdep command to  `rosdep install -i --from-path src --rosdistro humble -y --skip-keys pcl`. Hope it can help with your problem.

Comment: Here is another way might work, delete `<depend>PCL</depend>`, because ' <depend>pcl_conversions</depend>' will install 'pcl' while you using `rosdep`.